# Retrieve data from multiple sheets of single Excel file and insert into database using wso2 6.4.0 dss

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am new to wso2 6.4.0 I want to know whether is it possible to retrieve the data from multiple sheets of a single Excel file and then store that data into tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [query mode](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Exposing+Excel+Data+as+a+Data+Service#f5db2bb61b8344e48974c03db1fca17e) to query multiple sheets resides in the same excel file within a single query.

Comment: Hi, could you please share the some samples

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Exposing+Excel+Data+as+a+Data+Service#f5db2bb61b8344e48974c03db1fca17e has a tutorial with both query mode and non query mode

Comment: Hi, i have tried "Data retrieved from single excel sheet and insert into data base" with the above steps only. Its working finely, now i need to expose the data from mutiple sheets from single excel. Don't know  how to read multiple sheets from the single excel. Please guide me with that part alone.

Comment: Hi, please share some samples for multiple sheet data extraction.